# can't delete files recovered by photorec (linux noob)

Tags: permissions, delete, locate

Even though this may be a duplicate question i'm hoping to get an answer that will work for me and perhaps help others, seeing as how similar questions asked were unable to help me.
Any answers i've found do not work for me.

I have recovered files, and now i cannot delete them. says: permission denied.

i have a few recovered folders in different locations that i cannot delete.

I've read an answer saying type "sudo nautilus" in terminal...
After that im supposed to locate the files and delete them.

However i can not locate them via terminal, im not sure what im doing wrong.

Whenever i enter where they are (home/'my user name'/ or home/'my username'/Pictures or home/'my username'/Pictures/recup_dirvky.2 or wherever the folder is or the same thing with "cd" before home[which works for me with other things]) i get: "bash" "no such file or directory"

can anyone please explain what needs to be done, step by step, from giving myself permission, locating files to deleting them,  and maybe a brief explanation of what i'm doing wrong so i can learn please?